Where can I obtain the recorded data of GWs and corresponding best-matched templates for published events confirmed by LIGO please?
It is known that the LIGO-Virgo Collaboration (LVC) has released over 100 confirmed GW events. For each event, I believe that they possess the recorded raw data, which is a one-dimensional sequence of strain values in the time domain (after undergoing some filtering), and they also have the corresponding best-matched template, which is also a one-dimensional sequence givien by specific parameters such as black hole mass, spin, source distance, and more. The comparison between such data and template results in a small enough residual, which confirms the match.
If my above understanding is correct (please correct me if not), I hope to know where and how the LVC explicitly provides the concrete files of these data-template pairs for all the published 100+ GW events of binary mergers, and then, I hope to compare these data and templates myself to find out how different or consistent they are. Thank you very much.

https://gwosc.org/ ?

You might also be interested in https://github.com/gwastro

thank you. I also checked the gwosc.org, but seems these data covers a very long duration like 4096 seconds, and I hope to just find the data of the final stage of merger for every single event, together with corresponding best matched template.

@Wein, Maybe spend some more time looking on geoscience.org. The PE python notebooks should explain how to obtain the information you seek.
